# Deploying application artifacts to web servers

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, deployment, jenkins

I've been working on deployment automation. Major challenge am facing is copying the files from Jenkins to servers. Artifacts are present in workspace of the deployment job but I am not knowing how to deploy them by taking input parameters as userid and password. Since same job is used by release team and they only have access to production servers. I've searched online but seems there are not many articles for this common scenario. Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved without using tools such as puppet, preferably batch script or power shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the Jenkins SCP plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin

I haven't used it myself, but since you mentioned PowerShell, there is a Jenkins PowerShell plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin

The PublishOver plugin looks useful as well: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over

Alternatively you can run any arbitrary shell command using Jenkins shell script build step.

Comment: Good options but unfortunately these don't work in my case since these plugins store the username and password in the setup. So, any user having access to deployment page can deploy into production as well. Any thoughts how this can be achieved by forcing user to enter credentials?